# My WebApp where withSuccessHandler returns undefined

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-apps-script

I need help sorting this out. Everything seems to work fine until it gets to receive the results of request, where someting goes wrong. The idea of the project is a Web App, where user gets 2 fields for `name` and `date of birth`. After filling them the information is verified by checking in the spreadsheet with relevant information. If everything is okay, the program next obtains appropriate id with `getSheetId()`, generates `<iframe>` code for access and should be returning it with `HtmlService`. However, something makes it return `undefined`.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  Logger.log("Login is loading")
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      //.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);   
}

function evaluate(name, date) {
  var t = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1nQxfaQcNdM6S1roJs6gxTaZPtM5gOublch5jVKDhkho')
      .getSheetByName('key');
  Logger.log(t.getSheetId());
  Logger.log(name);
  Logger.log(date);
  var v = t.getRange("B2:D200");
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
    if (v.getCell(i, 2).getValue() == name) {
      Logger.log(v.getCell(i, 2).getValue());
      Logger.log(name & " = the name");
      Logger.log(new Date(v.getCell(i,3).getValue()).getTime());
      var pdate = date.split(".");
      Logger.log(new Date(pdate[2],pdate[1],pdate[0]).getTime());
      var t = v.getCell(i,3).getValue();
      Logger.log(pdate);
      Logger.log(t.getFullYear());
      Logger.log(t.getMonth());
      Logger.log(t.getDate());
      if (new Date(t.getFullYear(),t.getMonth()+1,t.getDate()).getTime() == new Date(pdate[2],pdate[1],pdate[0]).getTime()) {
        Logger.log("match found");
        include(v.getCell(i,1).getValue());
        break;
      } else {
        Logger.log("Bad date");
        return "<h2>Wrong Input. 404.</h2>";}
      }
  }
  if (i >= 199) {
    Logger.log("Bad name");
    return "<h2>Wrong Input. 404.</h2>";
  }  
}

var hhtml = "";

function include(name) {
  var html = '<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTeFjXOSsBRAKjbFLUSBGZOXtmjZO_4RtxxrQtXbk9sxZkF5Kdjs9OIs0tSQwekjYbOTn7JJ-_iCdeD/pubhtml?gid='
  var t = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1nQxfaQcNdM6S1roJs6gxTaZPtM5gOublch5jVKDhkho').getSheetByName(name);
  if (t == null) {
    Logger.log("Page not found");
    return "<h1>Wrong Input. 404.</h1>" 
  } else {
    html += t.getSheetId();
  }
  Logger.log(name);

  html += '&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false" width="80%" height="600"></iframe>'

  html += '<br><br><br><h3>Рейтинг групи</h3><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRF1MobEoKdxvO_SopGTvl-WzqEQ3nQXd6Jo_a7RTAg09yluO32AClwd4krWnVHXGQllPPwOsDeYYzN/pubhtml?gid=2096708929&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false" width="80%" height="600"></iframe>'
  Logger.log(html);
  hhtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).getContent();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).getContent();        
}

function getHtmlCode() {
  return hhtml;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="mainForm">
    <h2> Будь-ласка введіть своє прізвище українською мовою та дату народження у форматі день.місяць.рік (наприклад: 22.06.2018) </h2>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <div class="inline form-group">
                        <label for="name">Прізвище</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nameInput" style="width: 150px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline form-group">
                        <label for="date">Дата Народження</label>
                        <input type="text" id="dateInput" style="width: 150px;">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button class="action" type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
            </form>
         </div>

    <style>
        .hidden {
            display:none;
        }
        .form-group {
            margin: 2px 0px;
        }

        #submitButton {
            margin: 4px 0px;
        }

        body {
          margin-left: 50px;
        }

    </style>


    <script>

$(function(){
  console.log('startup')
  $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
    console.log("data get");

    function respondent(value)
    {
    $('#mainForm').toggleClass('hidden');
      console.log("script is success");
      console.log(value);
      document.getElementById('Response').innerHTML = value
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(respondent).evaluate(document.getElementById('nameInput').value, document.getElementById('dateInput').value);

  })
})

    </script>


    <div id="Response">

    <h2>Waiting for data...</h2>



    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning up your code formatting, it looks like you're only returning a value from `evaluate()` during the `Wrong Input` error conditions. Nothing is returned otherwise.

Perhaps you meant to add a line like this at the end of `evaluate()`:

```
return include(name);
```

---

Also, the `hhtml` global variable and `getHtmlCode()` functions aren't useful in the context of Apps Script. Each execution is in a separate instance with no state being carried over. Which mean `getHtmlCode()` will always return an empty string.

Comment: It did solve the problem. Thank you very much for your help!